# Hausdorff measure for Lebesgue measurable sets?

Tags: measure-theory, dimension-theory-analysis

As I never had a course which dealt with Hausdorff measures and every time I heard about Hausdorff measure I was only thinking using my intuition what that should be. So I decided to take a look at the definition, and try some typical examples. I am reading a chapter on Hausdorff measure of *Real Analysis* by Stein and Shakarchi.

I saw that they define the Hausdorff measure only for Borel measurable sets. My questions are:

> 1. Can we define Hausdorff measure for Lebesgue measurable sets or not?
> 2. If a set $E \subset \Bbb{R}^n$ has Lebesgue measure zero, then it's Hausdorff dimension is strictly smaller than $n$?

I am concerned about this since I sort of rushed out and 'proved' the following thing using Hausdorff measures:

> If $E \subset \Bbb{R}^n$ has Lebesgue measure zero and $f :\Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}^n$ is Lipschitz continuous then  $f(E)$ also has Lebesgue measure zero.

and I don't think my proof is right.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hausdorff **outer measure** is defined for all sets, and then we use the definition of Caratheodory to restrict it to a subalgebra of "measurable" sets to get the Hausdorff **measure**.  In $\mathbb R^n$, the $n$-dimensional Hausdorff outer measure is the same (up to a constant factor) as $n$-dimensional Lebesgue outer measure, so they have the same measurable sets as well.

Another counterexample to 2.  In interval $[n,n+1]\;$ take a subset with Hausdorff dimension $1-1/n\;$.  The union of these sets has Hausdorff dimension 1 but Lebesgue measure zero.

So to prove your fact about Lipschitz functions, you cannot do it by considering only sets with Hausdorff dimension ${}\lt 1$, you have to consider Lebesgue measure itself, and use its definition.  Try it, it's not too hard!

Comment: How is the union of the sets you want to construct of Lebesgue measure zero if it is already of Hausdorff measure $1-1/n$ when restricted to $[n,n+1]$? Am I missing something here?

Comment: (Did you intend to write 'of Hausdorff _dimension_ $1-1/n$'?)

Comment: Yes, corrected.

Comment: That's a much nicer counterexample.

Comment: Why the union of that sets has Hausdorff dimension 1?

Comment: Its subset in interval $[n,n+1]$ has dimension $1-1/n$, so the union has dimension at least $1-1/n$.   True for all $n$.

Answer (score 6):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_measure) has some useful information.

In $\mathbb{R}^d$, $d$-dimensional Hausdorff measure is equal to Lebesgue measure (up to scaling).  So once you have defined it for Borel sets, you can extend it to Lebesgue-measurable sets in the same way: any Lebesgue-measurable set is of the form $A = B \cup C$ where $B$ is Borel and $C$ is Lebesgue measurable with $m(C) = 0$, so define the Hausdorff measure of $A$ to be the Hausdorff measure of $B$. Just as with Lebesgue measure, this gives you a countably additive complete measure.

Wiki also gives a counterexample to your question 2: the image of a 2-dimensional Brownian motion has Hausdorff dimension 2 but its 2-dimensional Hausdorff measure (i.e. its Lebesgue measure) is zero (almost surely).